# Display elements inside the anchor tag one below the other in Angular Material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I want to display the elemrnts inside the anchor tag in a single line in Angular Material. I need the CSS style to achive the output.

My HTML:

```
<a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['dashboard']" style="text-align: center;">
  <mat-icon style="height:15px;display: block;">dashboard</mat-icon>
  <span style="display: block;">Dashboard</span>
</a>
```

[image: Screenshot of a dashboard link with a dashboard icon and the text "Dashboard"]

Comment: Please check this stackblitz link and let me know i'm getting your point right or wrong https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x1frjr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

On your a tag, try the "display: inline" or "inline-block" alternatively, depending on if you need more elements in it or more flexibility, you can use "display: flex" and set "flex-direction: row"

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['dashboard']" style="text-align: center; display: flex;">
     <mat-icon style="height:15px;display: block;">dashboard</mat-icon>
     <span style="display: block;">Dashboard</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Can you send me an URL where I can directly look at?

Answer (score 0):

As of now from me this worked

```
<a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['dashboard']" class="checkcss">
            <div class="align-cont"  >
              <div class="icon-style"> <mat-icon style="height:15px">dashboard</mat-icon></div>
              <div class="text-style" > <span >Dashboard</span> </div>
            </div> 
        </a>
```